# Minicom not capturing data correctly

Tags: linux, centos, hyperterminal

I have an issue where i have connected my linux server to a serial port. There is a continous flow of data from serial port which comes through epabx.

In Minicom i get first call's data and from second call it goes offline.
I dont see any data.

Can some one help me on this.

Comment: You try to connect serial console of one linux host to com-port another linux host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the help given by you. Finally i have got the error solved.
God knows how i started getting the data.

But still i am listing the steps i performed to get correct data.

Sometimes data from serial port wont be capturing in the processing form application.

It may be because of the following issues.

1.Serial port not connected properly.
2.Serial port cable not working.
3.Some pins on serial port are damaged or connection lost.
   Note: For above all reasons contact the client person or person in charge of epabx systems.

4.Data not getting displayed on hypertiminal.
    This is a common issue in linux which uses minicom as hyperterminal.

Sol: Check the version of the minicom before running it on linux. If the version is minocom 2.1 then some process would be blocking the incoming data.

Uninstall minicom 2.1 and reinstall minicom 2.0

It is said that gate 8 process would block the incoming data.

Answer (score 1):

minicom may be responding to control characters in your data. I'd recommend something simple but effective like

```
od -t x1 -t a /dev/ttySomething
```

to dump your data in both hex and as text.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check that your port settings are correct i.e. bitrate, parity, stop bits, flow-control. Sometimes, when your settings are not correct, you will end up with weird results. Also, you need to check that your protocol is only sending texts as Carl mentioned.

Comment: Yes i have checked. Everything seems to be fine. the settings take 9600 baud rate. 8n1 settings.